# Почему программа завершает выполнение?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Всю голову уже себе сломал, может кто подскажет.
Есть следующий код, передающий суть проблемы:

```
var body = "";
for(var i=0; i<=5000; i++) {
  body += "if(str==='value" + i + "') 1==1;\n";
}
body += "return str;";

var f1 = new Function("str", body);
var f2 = new Function("str", body);

console.log(f1('test1'));
console.log(f2('test2'));

// main loop
for(var i=0; i<100000; i++) {
  f1("string");
  f2("string");
  console.log(i);
}

console.log("fin!");
```

Почему цикл main loop не отрабатывает до конца и программа завершает работу (при этом никакой информации об ошибках не выводится)?
Запускать в nodejs.

пожалуйста, не пишите комментарии относительно функциональности кода, проблема не в этом. Цель- выполнить в цикле две функции f1 и f2 100000 раз. У меня этот цикл прерывается на примерно 2000 итерации (плюс-минус). Почему прерывается - вот в чем вопрос первый вопрос и как этого избежать - второй.
При этом интересная особенность- одна функция в цикле исполняется исправно 100000 раз. Я пробовал запускать этот код на разных машинах, результат примерно одинаковый.

Comment: "не отрабатывает до конца" - а докуда?

Comment: Где запускать то? В браузере все работает

Comment: У меня последняя итерация цикла i=~2000. Забыл указать - версия Nodejs 5.0.0

Comment: в браузере всё работает. может сброс соединения по таймауту?

Comment: У меня в браузере тоже не работает... Не похоже на таймаут - быстро отваливается.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: @zelta какая ж тут магия? http://javascript.ru/Function

Comment: Ооох, позор мне, позор! (удалил нафиг комментарий =)

Comment: "прерывает" - nodejs завершает исполнение и высвечивается приглашение консоли операционной системы?
или просто приостанавливается счетчик и можно дальше работать с repl nodejs?

Comment: @NumminorihSF, первое

Comment: тогда рискну предположить, что процесс уходит в OOM (а операционная система молча его гасит), т.к. данный пример у меня выполнился, но по ходу отожрался до 5гб используемой памяти, правда в самом процессе исполнения отработал сборщик мусора и, ближе к концу исполнения, все опять улеглось.

Comment: Только что завел на виртуалке с 2гб оперативной памяти, закрашилась довольно таки молча, просто в консоль отписало "Убито". В сислоге - сообщение об ООМ и что система убивает процесс.

Comment: @NumminorihSF, спасибо за эксперимент. Есть варианты как это обойти? Если использовать eval вместо new Function, то все отрабатывает, но с eval это занимает на порядок больше времени.

Comment: Не могу предположить даже. Самое интересное в том, что если функцию сгенерированную записать в файл, использовать на ней require, и вызывать - происходит то же самое. С асинхронным вызовом через `setImmediate` ровно тоже самое.

Comment: Всё работает: `99999
fin!

D:\Temp>node -v
v5.8.0`. Предлагаю переустановить node.js (а заодно обновить). И в repl-варианте работает.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по комментариям у вас просто выедает всю память и процесс тушится. При чем у ноды есть ограничение - она есть только 1,5 Гб(ограничение пришло еще с того момента, когда V8 был движком только для хрома). В общем надо просто процесс запускать с флагом --max-old-space-size и ставить потом желаемый объем. Если уже вашего объема будет недостаточно, то тут уже ничем не помочь.

Чтобы работало быстрее попробуйте уменьшить количество console.log - они здорово тратят время на вывод.

Comment: А где в коде потребление памяти? Да ещё и в таких объёмах?